# function MySQL does not exist

Tags: mysql, function

I'm creating my first function, with the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CTRLPRODUCAO.COMPARATOTAIS (AG INT, P INT, ANO INT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    (...)
END
```

When I run the command, received the return of the Workbench: "0 row (s) affected". Is it ok?

When I run
    SELECT CTRLPRODUCAO.COMPARATOTAIS (1, 9, 2011) AS TEST;

I get

> "Error Code: 1305 FUNCTION CTRLPRODUCAO.COMPARATOTAIS does not exist"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use a `.` in the function name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't insert a . in your function name.

As far as i know, in MySQL, the . is interpeted as a kind of join and in your example, MySQL is looking for the function COMPARATOTAIS in CTRLPRODUCAO table.